# Open external links in phone gap 1.6.0

Tags: ios, cordova

How can I open external links inside an iOS using the latest version of phonegap?

Comment: i am using version phonegap 1.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution**

unComment this block in **MainViewController.m**

```
/* Comment out the block below to over-ride */
/*

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView 
{
    return [super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView];
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error 
{
    return [super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
*/
```

and replace this complete function

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

with

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
 {
     NSURL *url = [request URL];
     if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) 
     {
        return YES;
     }
     else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
     }
 }
```